# Numpy index, get bands of width 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

I am wondering if there is a way it index/slice a numpy array, such that one can get every other band of 2 elements.  In other words, given:

```
test = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]])
```

I would like to get the array:

```
[[1,  2,  5,  6],
 [9, 10, 13, 14]]
```

Thoughts on how this can be accomplished with slicing/indexing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that difficult with a few smart reshapes :)

```
test.reshape((4, 4))[:, :2].reshape((2, 4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
>>> test
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

You can do:

```
>>> test.reshape(-1,2)[::2].reshape(-1,4)
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14]])
```

Which works even for different shapes of initial arrays:

```
>>> test2
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16])
>>> test2.reshape(-1,2)[::2].reshape(-1,4)
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14]])

>>> test3
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
>>> test3.reshape(-1,2)[::2].reshape(-1,4)
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14]])
```

How it works:

```
1. Reshape into two columns by however many rows:
>>> test.reshape(-1,2)
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12],
       [13, 14],
       [15, 16]])

2. Stride the array by stepping every second element
>>> test.reshape(-1,2)[::2]
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10],
       [13, 14]])

3. Set the shape you want of 4 columns, however many rows:
>>> test.reshape(-1,2)[::2].reshape(-1,4)
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14]])
```